# Cannot find a way to know if iframe loaded html correctly on a lightning:container

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-container

We are trying to build a React application that loads inside a `lightning:container`. Since there is an issue where sometimes you might hit a `403 Forbidden` error if the page setup has more than 1 application using `lightning:container` (I believe there is race condition with the _CONFIRMATIONTOKEN where sometimes it uses the same one for multiple loads of the html of these containers). So, when that happens, sadly the html doesn't even load and we are stuck with a blank page.

```
<aura:component ...>
  <aura:if isTrue="{!v.iframeNotFailedToLoad}">
    <lightning:container
      aura:id="containerId"
      onmessage="{!c.handleInnerMessage}"
      src="{!$Resource.resource_name + '/index.html'}"
      onerror="{!c.handleIframeError}"
    />
  </aura:if> 
</aura:component>
```

**Brief description of what we have so far:**

To address that we tried to look for the `load` javascript event of the iframe that is created on runtime inside the `lightning:container` and then using that event to search if the React application sent a message or not the Aura Component. In case there wasn't any message we can guarantee that the iframe finished loading and that something went wrong to load the html (assuming in this case we hit the 403 error). In that case, we change the value of the `isTrue` attribute in the `aura:if` to trigger and destroy and then recreate the `lightning:container`, allowing us to use a different _CONFIRMATIONTOKEN and therefore loading the app correctly.

**The issue we are having:**

This is the way we are trying to hear for the `load` event:

```
  const iframeContainer = cmp.find("containerId");
    if (iframeContainer && iframeContainer.isValid()) {
      const internalDiv = iframeContainer.getElement();
      if (internalDiv) {
        const iframe = internalDiv.firstChild;
        if (iframe) {
          iframe.addEventListener("load", () => {
            this.iframeLoadEvent(cmp, iframe);
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

Although this worked well when doing dev testing, once we created the package and installed it on an organization it seems that the LockerService is preventing us from doing `iframeContainer.getElement()`. Therefore, this whole thing just fails.

So, going to to the question: is there a way to identify correctly if we are hitting the 403 issue or knowing if the iframe finished loading but failed to load the HTML so that we can restart it AND also something that works well with the LockerService?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't onerror give you what you need?

Comment: @sfdcfox no, it doesn't. When it fails with the 403 error to load the html onerror does not execute